# Can I replace my HE-11 visa for a cruise to Cuba this month?

Tags: visas, cuba

My cruise leaves from Miami on April 20, 2019.  My spouse, who has Alzheimer’s, has thrown the visa away.  Will I be able to get a copy of it in time for my trip?

Comment: Have you contacted the Embassy that issued it?

Comment: Should I contact the  Cuban Embassy in Washington DC?

Comment: Did you hear back from them, what was the outcome?